# Spring Batch Chaining readers and processors before writer

Tags: spring-batch, chaining

I would like to achieve the following chain in Spring batch:

(A)ItemReader[First Input] -> (A)ItemProcessor [First Input] -> (B)ItemReader [using processed Input to collect second input from another source] -> (B)ItemProcessor [ using processed first input nd second input ] -> {repeat B} -> ItemWriter (final result)

Does any body know how to do this in Spring Batch?
Thanks.

Comment: I wrote some code to illustate steps chaining based on the spring bot -batch sample. [Check it out here](https://github.com/salemba/spring-boot-use-cases)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend this approach.  I'd recommend a much more simple:

(A)ItemReader[First Input] -> (A)ItemProcessor [First Input] -> (B)ItemProcessor [Transforms first input into second input] -> (B)ItemProcessor [ using processed first input nd second input ] -> {repeat B} -> ItemWriter (final result)

An `ItemProcessor` can be used for both enrichment or transformation.  The reader in your flow for B I'd replace for an `ItemProcessor` that transforms the first input to the second input.

Comment: Thank you Michael for your answer. I've been reading your Apress book (great work:) ) today. But I couldn't find a similar scenario for for chaining steps.

Comment: So, effectively, you're using (B)ItemProcessor as a reader ? I ask because I have a similar situation (reading with REST) where I need to do multiple reads based on information retrieved in the first read...

Answer (score -1):

I don't see here any problem. You just store results of processing A to some storage and read it in `(B) ItemReader`.

Main question here arises whether you want your jobs be restartable or not.

- If not you can store intermediate results in some in-memory hash-map or anything else.
- If you want it to be restartable (e.g. fail safe) - then prefer some persistent storage.

Comment: Thank you. Could you point me to a similar example? I think I will e using the JobExection or maybe the StepExecution to pas in memory results.